# CORS issue with lightning out used in external website

Tags: heroku, cors

I have deployed a nodejs application on Heroku, it has one lightning component embedded using lightning out. But I am getting the below error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote >resource at https://myorg-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/sampleapp.app?>aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT. (Reason: CORS header 'Access->Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I have added my domain in CORS as well.

All works fine, If I login into Salesforce in next tab of browser to this application.

How I can resolve this if I don't login to Salesforce using the same browser.

Comment: does your app meet all the following requirements? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_requirements.htm

Comment: Yes it does. It works fine when I am logged in Salesforce org, but has issue when accessing website without logging on

Comment: can you try providing a minimal code sample for other to reproduce the error?

Comment: I followed this blog: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/use-lightning-components-on-external-websites-lightning-out/

Comment: Not able to resolve this issue. Please help it's urgent

Comment: if it is urgent, can you try providing a minimal code sample for others to reproduce the error? as it was asked 3 days ago...No links, explain in your post and provide minimal code samples.

Comment: Hi @InderWaraich Did you resolve it, I am facing the same errors. thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the url that you access the dependency app on - you may get a different url back from login flow. See my response [Lightning Out session expired from external page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161417/lightning-out-session-expired-from-external-page/237897#237897)